# When does a using-statement box its argument, when it's a struct?

Tags: c#, struct, idisposable, using, boxing

I have some questions about the following code:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    public struct Disposable : IDisposable
    {
        public void Dispose() { }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (Test()) { }
        }

        static Disposable Test()
        {
            return new Disposable();
        }
    }
}
```

My questions are:

- Will the using-statement that operates on the `Disposable` struct, returned from `Test()` box the struct, or not?
- How can I find the answer myself?

To try to find out myself, I inspected the IL produced by the above code, and here's the IL for the `Main(...)` method:

```
.method private hidebysig static void Main(string[] args) cil managed
{
    .entrypoint
    .maxstack 1
    .locals init (
        [0] valuetype ConsoleApplication2.Disposable CS$3$0000)
    L_0000: call valuetype ConsoleApplication2.Disposable ConsoleApplication2.Program::Test()
    L_0005: stloc.0 
    L_0006: leave.s L_0016
    L_0008: ldloca.s CS$3$0000
    L_000a: constrained ConsoleApplication2.Disposable
    L_0010: callvirt instance void [mscorlib]System.IDisposable::Dispose()
    L_0015: endfinally 
    L_0016: ret 
    .try L_0006 to L_0008 finally handler L_0008 to L_0016
}
```

I suspect the call to the virtual method there, on `L_0010` will introduce a boxing operation, but the actual `box` instruction is not here.

The reason I'm asking is that a while ago, probably 1-2 years, I saw online an "optimization" of the using-statement someone commented on. The case was where the using-statement was used as syntax for a short-time lock on an object, where the lock was acquired in the method, and a struct was returned, which when disposed of, would release the lock, code like this:

```
using (LockTheObject())
{
    // use the object
}
```

and the comment was that by changing the return type of the `LockTheObject` method from `IDisposable` to the actual struct used, boxing was avoided.

But I'm wondering if this is true, or still true.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? If, in order to see the box operation, I'll have to inspect the runtime assembly code, please show me an example of what to look for, I'm well versed in assembly code so that's not a problem, but nothing jumped out at me when I looked at that either.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It appears as though any value type that gets put in a `using` statement will not be boxed.  This appears to be a C# optimization as boxing is only omitted when a value type that implements `IDisposable` is in a `using` statement, not in any other context.

For more info please see [The Using Statement And Disposable Value Types](http://haacked.com/archive/2006/08/11/TheUsingStatementAndDisposableValueTypes.aspx):

> A while ago Ian Griffiths wrote about
>   an improvement to his TimedLock class
>   in which he changed it from a class to
>   a struct. This change resulted in a
>   value type that implements
>   IDisposable. I had a nagging question
>   in the back of my mind at the time
>   that I quickly forgot about. The
>   question is wouldn’t instances of that
>   type get boxed when calling Dispose?

And also [Oh No! Not the TimedLock Again!](http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2004/04/26/yetmoretimedlocking):

> John Sands points out a flaw in the
>   code I showed in a recent blog for
>   using timeouts on locks without
>   abandoning most of the convenience of
>   C#'s `lock` keyword .

Comment: The interaction between constrained and callvirt was what I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 7):

This is a duplicate of [If my struct implements IDisposable will it be boxed when used in a using statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2412981/if-my-struct-implements-idisposable-will-it-be-boxed-when-used-in-a-using-statem/2413844#2413844)

UPDATE: This question was [the subject of my blog in March of 2011](http://ericlippert.com/2011/03/14/to-box-or-not-to-box/). Thanks for the great question!

Andrew Hare's answer is correct; I just wanted to add an interesting extra note. The optimization we emit -- of using constrained callvirt to skip the boxing when possible -- is actually strictly speaking a violation of the C# specification. The spec states that the finally block we generate for a value type resource is:

```
     finally 
     {
         ((IDisposable)resource).Dispose();
     }
```

which clearly is a boxing conversion on a value type. It is possible to construct contrived scenarios in which the lack of boxing in the implementation is visible.

(Thanks are due to Vladimir Reshetnikov for pointing out this spec violation to me.)

Comment: I've sometimes bemoaned the lack of any syntax to specify a "reinterpret without boxing" typecast.  Since `resource` must be of a type which would satisfy an `IDisposable` constraint, I wonder if the spec could say that the behavior would be equivalent to calling `static void DisposeIt<T>(ref T it) where it:IDisposable {it.Dispose();}`, except that the C# compiler would likely generate the code in-line [even if the C# compiler doesn't in-line it, it would seem the JITter might].

Comment: Hi Eric, I wonder if the constrained callvirt is, as of now, still a violation of the C# specification.

Answer (score 5):

Instance methods on a value type take a `this` parameter as their first argument similar to how instance methods on reference types do. However, the parameter in this case is a managed pointer to the object's data, not a reference to a boxed object. You might find it laid out in memory like this:

```
Unboxed object:
-----------------------------------------
|              DATA                     |
-----------------------------------------
 ^ managed pointer to struct

Boxed object:
------------------------------------------------------------
| GC/Object header |              [Boxed] DATA             |
------------------------------------------------------------
                    ^ The 'unbox' opcode gives a managed pointer to the boxed data
 ^ A *reference* to any instance of a reference type or boxed object, points here
```

`DATA` is the same in both of these cases¹.

Instance methods on a value type expect the managed pointer to data *specifically* so boxing the objects is not required. As you see above, the `constrained` opcode is used before the call. It tells the runtime that the following `callvirt` instruction is receiving a managed pointer to a `ConsoleApplication2.Disposable` struct instead of the object reference it normally receives. In doing so, the JIT can resolve the sealed overload of `Dispose()` implemented by the struct and call it directly without boxing the object. Without the `constrained` prefix, the object passed to the `callvirt` instruction would have to be an object reference, because the standard virtual call dynamic resolution procedure is based on the fact that the GC/Object header is *always* in the expected location - and yes, this would force boxing for value types.

¹ We'll go ahead and ignore `Nullable<T>` for now.