# Do all value types become subject to GC in when async function is suspended?

Tags: c#, async-await, garbage-collection

Say you have:

- An async function, in which...
- ... A variable with a value type being initialised before an async/await point
- Said value type does not escape the function

```
  readonly struct MyStruct : IDisposable
  {
    // ... fields, IDisposable implementation and so on ...
  }

  async Task test()
  {
    using var myStructInstance = GetMyStruct(); // Some external function which creates and returns an instance of MyStruct
    await SomethingElse();
  }
```

What is the impact on the overall GC behaviour of the system, depending on whether the subsequent async call executes synchronously, or truly asynchronously?

In particular,

- Is it correct to assume "myStructInstance" will remain purely on the stack (no heap allocations) in case `SomethingElse()` returns synchronously?
- What happens if SomethingElse() does suspend the async execution here?
  Will "myStructInstance" be promoted to an individual GC-tracked object on the heap? Or, since technically its lifetime is strictly tied to the generated async state machine, would it be part of the underlying memory layout of the state machine itself, and not be tracked as an individual object on the heap/by the GC?

As you can probably tell, my general aim is to figure out if locally used value types in async functions could potentially contribute to GC pressure, or if they generally have minimal to no impact.

Comment: Could you remove the IDisposable from the example? I think it will trigger people beyond the actual question you want to have answered.

Comment: Definitely edit out that extremely controversial disposable struct... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7914423/struct-and-idisposable. Also consider clarifying what you don't understand - clearly you know how async methods compiled into state machine and presumably what values are likely to be promoted to fields... It's kind of unclear why do you think there is any magic beyond looking at generated code...

Comment: Value types are only subject to garbage collection if they're boxed. That's true whether they're truly local or they're captured in a lambda or an async state machine.  When they're captured, the captured context is subject to garbage collection, but the value type exists within that memory and is not separately subject to garbage collection.

Comment: But, the rules should just remain the same.  If there is a reference to an object on the managed heap (reference type instances, value types wrapped up in reference-ish objects because of an async state-machine), it won't be collected.  It can only become eligible for collection once there are no outstanding references.  I'm comfortable believing that the Frameworky folks over at MSFT didn't break this rule here.

Comment: They generally have minimal impact. This behavior is not guaranteed. As one example, it takes a less-efficient but more-debugging-friendly approach if you're running in the debugger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Or, since technically its lifetime is strictly tied to the generated async state machine, would it be part of the underlying memory layout of the state machine itself

In current compiler implementation the local variables used after the await will be stored as part of the async state machine. You can use https://sharplab.io/ to dabble with the decompilation.

Consider the following code:

```
public class C {
  async Task test()
  {
    var o = new object();
    var o1 = new object();
    var myStructInstance = new MyStruct(1); 
    Console.WriteLine(o1);
    await Task.Yield();
    Console.WriteLine(o);
    Console.WriteLine(myStructInstance.I);
  }
}

readonly struct MyStruct
{
    public MyStruct(int i) => I = i;
    public int I {get;}
}
```

This will lead to `o` and `myStructInstance` stored in the fields (but not `o1`):

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Auto)]
[CompilerGenerated]
private struct <test>d__0 : IAsyncStateMachine
{
    // ...

    private object <o>5__2;

    private MyStruct <myStructInstance>5__3;

}
```

[Demo @sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io/#v2:D4AQTAjAsAUCAMACEECsBuWsQGZlkQGFEBvWRZADmQDZEAXAUwGd6AKASnNO4oDcAhgCdEAe0QBeRADtGAdzEAjAFaMAxuw6YYFfsLERJM+UtUbO23YkEiAtgE8AyvSEBXDQElprAdLWMjWQUAWScXd3YILUReZAgATjZRKMtdEHjaADoATQBLRgAbABMLWJRE0S0yhLYHZzdPb3pff0yPKp1EAF9YHphYIUYBItFpAvtEVgb6RFD6iNgyTopcWbDptlzpGdyOSQA+RA8jXNSVvC2Z45IAc0Z6dD6uoA).

So no, `myStructInstance` should not be boxed as a separate object.

> my general aim is to figure out if locally used value types in async functions could potentially contribute to GC pressure, or if they generally have minimal to no impact.

In theory yes - if you drill down into decompiled state machine you will see that at some point it can be "boxed" into internal `IAsyncStateMachineBox` interface (it happens when task has not finished, [`AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.AwaitUnsafeOnCompleted`](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Runtime/CompilerServices/AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.cs,bd420b0c9357b57d) is called which will result in the [`GetStateMachineBox`](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Runtime/CompilerServices/AsyncTaskMethodBuilderT.cs,18cb1545fb03ae0c) call), so the whole statemachine will be placed on heap and the size of the state machine depends on captured variables. So yes some effect is there but I would argue that in most cases it is negligible.