# SemaphoreSlim.WaitAsync before/after try block

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, locking, semaphore

I know that in the sync world the first snippet is right, but what's about [`WaitAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim.waitasync) and async/await magic? Please give me some .NET internals.

```
await _semaphore.WaitAsync();
try
{
    // todo
}
finally
{
    _semaphore.Release();
}
```

or

```
try
{
    await _semaphore.WaitAsync();
    // todo
}
finally
{
    _semaphore.Release();
}
```

Comment: `async/await` doesn't change how exceptions behave *inside* `async` method. It only changes how exceptions are [propagated *outside* `async` method](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21082631/1768303). So, what was right for "sync word" is still right here.

Comment: This article explains that the same question was considered when implementing ````lock() {}````: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/03/06/locks-and-exceptions-do-not-mix/

Answer (score 35):

According to MSDN, `SemaphoreSlim.WaitAsync` may throw:

1. `ObjectDisposedException` - If the semaphore has been disposed
2. `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` - if you choose the overload which accepts an `int` and it is a negative number (excluding -1)

In both cases, the `SemaphoreSlim` wont acquire the lock, which makes it unnessacery to release it in a `finally` block.

One thing to note is if the object is disposed or null in the second example, the finally block will execute and either trigger another exception or call `Release` which might have not acquired any locks to release in the first place.

To conclude, I would go with the former for consistency with non-async locks and avoiding exceptions in the `finally` block

Comment: Wouldn't a `Release` where a `WaitAsync` failed still exit the semaphore once?

Comment: Definitely would cause a redundant call. Fixed my answer

Answer (score 15):

Both options are dangerous if we think about `ThreadAbortException`, an exception that can happen in older .NET Framework code although **it's important to note that it won't occur in newer .NET Core code**, as Microsoft say: "Even though this type exists in .NET Core and .NET 5+, since Abort is not supported, the common language runtime won't ever throw ThreadAbortException."

1. Consider **Option 1** and `ThreadAbortException` happening between `WaitAsync` and `try`. In this case a semaphore lock would be acquired but never released. Eventually that would lead to a deadlock.

```
await _semaphore.WaitAsync();

// ThreadAbortException happens here

try
{
    // todo
}
finally
{
    _semaphore.Release();
}
```

2. Now in **Option 2**, if `ThreadAbortException` happens before a lock has been acquired, we'd still try to release somebody else's lock, or we'd get `SemaphoreFullException` if the semaphore is not locked.

```
try
{
    // ThreadAbortException happens here

    await _semaphore.WaitAsync();
    // todo
}
finally
{
    _semaphore.Release();
}
```

Theoretically, we can go with **Option 2** and track whether a lock was actually acquired. For that we're going to put lock acquisition and tracking logic into another (inner) `try-finally` statement in a `finally` block. The reason is that `ThreadAbortException` doesn't interrupt `finally` block execution. So we'll have something like this:

```
var isTaken = false;

try
{
    try
    {           
    }
    finally
    {
        await _semaphore.WaitAsync();
        isTaken = true;
    }

    // todo
}
finally
{
    if (isTaken)
    {
        _semaphore.Release();
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, we're still not safe. The problem is that `Thread.Abort` locks the calling thread until the aborting thread leaves a protected region (the inner `finally` block in our scenario). That can lead to a deadlock. To avoid infinite or long-running semaphore awaiting we can interrupt it periodically and give `ThreadAbortException` a chance to interrupt execution. Now the logic feels safe.

```
var isTaken = false;

try
{
    do
    {
        try
        {
        }
        finally
        {
            isTaken = await _semaphore.WaitAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
        }
    }
    while(!isTaken);

    // todo
}
finally
{
    if (isTaken)
    {
        _semaphore.Release();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would we at all consider handling ThreadAbortException if we are sure that our code does not call Thread.Abort?

Comment: Your question is very valid, especially in terms of the changes introduced in .NET Core, where `Thread.Abort` was superseded with a more safe approach based on CancellationToken. There is a nice thread regarding that: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/11369

As for .NET Framework projects, I'd say, considering ThreadAbortException is still valid, since it's hard to foresee all ways where it can be thrown - that includes 3rd party libraries as well as consumers.

Comment: Just curious; instead of an empty `try` block with work in `finally`, why not call `WaitAsync()` in the `try` block and then use an empty `catch`?

Comment: We wanted to ensure the `isTaken` variable is always updated with the result of `WaitAsync()` invocation. A `ThreadAbortException` may happen after semaphore lock is acquired, but before the variable gets updated. That's why we put these operations into `finally` block guaranteeing they will not be interrupted. Unlikely to the `finally` block, the `try-catch` can be interrupted by the `ThreadAbortException`. Hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 12):

If there's an exception inside `WaitAsync` the semaphore was **not** acquired, so a `Release` is unnecessary and should be avoided. You should go with the first snippet.

If you're worried about exceptions in the actual acquiring of the semaphore (which aren't likely, other than `NullReferenceException`) you could try-catch it independently:

```
try
{
    await _semaphore.WaitAsync();
}
catch
{
    // handle
}

try
{
    // todo
}
finally
{
    _semaphore.Release();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This is an attempted improvement of Bill Tarbell's [`LockSync`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24139084/semaphoreslim-waitasync-before-after-try-block/60109694#60109694) extension method for the [`SemaphoreSlim`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim) class. By using a value-type `IDisposable` wrapper and a `ValueTask` return type, it is possible to reduce significantly the additional allocations beyond what the `SemaphoreSlim` class allocates by itself.

```
public static ReleaseToken Lock(this SemaphoreSlim semaphore,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    semaphore.Wait(cancellationToken);
    return new ReleaseToken(semaphore);
}

public static async ValueTask<ReleaseToken> LockAsync(this SemaphoreSlim semaphore,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    await semaphore.WaitAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
    return new ReleaseToken(semaphore);
}

public readonly struct ReleaseToken : IDisposable
{
    private readonly SemaphoreSlim _semaphore;
    public ReleaseToken(SemaphoreSlim semaphore) => _semaphore = semaphore;
    public void Dispose() => _semaphore?.Release();
}
```

Usage example (sync/async):

```
using (semaphore.Lock())
{
    DoStuff();
}

using (await semaphore.LockAsync())
{
    await DoStuffAsync();
}
```

The synchronous `Lock` is always allocation-free, regardless of whether the semaphore is acquired immediately or after a blocking wait. The asynchronous `LockAsync` is also allocation-free, but only when the semaphore is acquired synchronously (when it's [`CurrentCount`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim.currentcount) happens to be positive at the time). When there is contention and the `LockAsync` must complete asynchronously, 144 bytes are allocated additionally to the standard `SemaphoreSlim.WaitAsync` allocations (which are 88 bytes without `CancellationToken`, and 497 bytes with cancelable `CancellationToken` as of .NET 5 on a 64 bit machine).

From [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.valuetask-1#remarks):

> The use of the `ValueTask<TResult>` type is supported starting with C# 7.0, and is not supported by any version of Visual Basic.

`readonly` [structs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/struct) are available beginning with C# 7.2.

Also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2412981/if-my-struct-implements-idisposable-will-it-be-boxed-when-used-in-a-using-statem) is explained why the `IDisposable` `ReleaseToken` struct is not boxed by the [`using`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) statement.

**Note:** Personally [I am not a fan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75570920/what-are-the-differences-between-asyncex-asynclock-and-scott-hanselmans-asynclo/75575557#75575557) of (mis)using the `using` statement for purposes other than releasing unmanaged resources.

Answer (score 2):

Your first option is preferred to avoid calling release in the event that the Wait call threw.  Though, with **c#8.0** we can write things so that we don't have so much ugly nesting on each our methods requiring the use of a semaphore.

Usage:

```
public async Task YourMethod() 
{
  using await _semaphore.LockAsync();
  // todo
} //the using statement will auto-release the semaphore
```

Here's the extension method:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace YourNamespace
{
  public static class SemaphorSlimExtensions
  {
    public static IDisposable LockSync(this SemaphoreSlim semaphore)
    {
      if (semaphore == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(semaphore));

      var wrapper = new AutoReleaseSemaphoreWrapper(semaphore);
      semaphore.Wait();
      return wrapper;
    }

    public static async Task<IDisposable> LockAsync(this SemaphoreSlim semaphore)
    {
      if (semaphore == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(semaphore));

      var wrapper = new AutoReleaseSemaphoreWrapper(semaphore);
      await semaphore.WaitAsync();
      return wrapper;
    }
  }
}
```

And the IDisposable wrapper:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace YourNamespace
{
  public class AutoReleaseSemaphoreWrapper : IDisposable
  {
    private readonly SemaphoreSlim _semaphore;

    public AutoReleaseSemaphoreWrapper(SemaphoreSlim semaphore )
    {
      _semaphore = semaphore;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
      try
      {
        _semaphore.Release();
      }
      catch { }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Why are you suppressing a possible exception of the `_semaphore.Release();` call? A `SemaphoreFullException` occurrence is certainly something that at least should be logged, in order to receive the developer's attention.

Comment: Because there's not enough context in the sample to meaningfully handle the exception.  The reader may want to simply log it, destroy all instances that made use of the semaphore, or perhaps fully terminate their app.  The choice is theirs - this is only a succinct sample to demonstrate the concept.

Comment: Bill my understand is that the `AutoReleaseSemaphoreWrapper` is library-worthy code. It's not a piece of application code, intended to be customized to the special needs of the application at hand. So IMHO the [general rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/exceptions/exception-handling) about handling exceptions apply: If you don't know how to handle it, let the exception propagate.

Answer (score 0):

This is a mix of an answer and a question.

From an article about `lock(){}` implementation:

> The problem here is that if the compiler generates a no-op instruction between the monitor enter and the try-protected region then it is possible for the runtime to throw a thread abort exception after the monitor enter but before the try. In that scenario, the finally never runs so the lock leaks, probably eventually deadlocking the program. It would be nice if this were impossible in unoptimized and optimized builds.
>   (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/03/06/locks-and-exceptions-do-not-mix/)

Of course, `lock` is not the same, but from this note we could conclude, that it might also be better to put the `SemaphoreSlim.WaitAsync()` inside the `try` block, if it also offered a way to determine if the lock was acquired successfully (as `Monitor.Enter` as described in the article does). However, `SemaphoreSlim` does not offer such a mechanism.

This article about the implementation of `using` says:

```
using (Font font1 = new Font("Arial", 10.0f)) 
{
    byte charset = font1.GdiCharSet;
}
```

is transformed to:

```
{
  Font font1 = new Font("Arial", 10.0f);
  try
  {
    byte charset = font1.GdiCharSet;
  }
  finally
  {
    if (font1 != null)
      ((IDisposable)font1).Dispose();
  }
}
```

If a noop can be generated between a `Monitor.Enter()` and its immediately following `try`, wouldn't the same problem apply to the transformed `using` code, either?

Maybe this implementation of `AsyncSemaphore` 
https://github.com/Microsoft/vs-threading/blob/81db9bbc559e641c2b2baf2b811d959f0c0adf24/src/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading/AsyncSemaphore.cs

and extensions for `SemaphoreSlim`
https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/blob/02341dbaf3df62e97c4bbaeb6d6606d345f9cda5/src/Nito.AsyncEx.Coordination/SemaphoreSlimExtensions.cs

are also interesting.