# When to take (await) a Semaphore? As local as possible?

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await

We have software that controls a machine. The machine has the concept of "Jobs" that it can run in production. A pretty common concept. More details on what the machine does is irrelevant.

The software is written in C#, and lives on quite a while. Concepts like async-await are adapted, but lots of legacy is not updated, and is made thread-safe with `lock` keywords.

When we want to migrate "thread safe" code from a synchronous interfaces to an async interface, we need to replace `lock` statements with `SemaphoreSlim` protection.

### Some background first

I have a more general question in the end, but please allow me to illustrate the problem first.

Below some "pseudo" code, written without an IDE, just to make the present the question/topic. If I made a typo, please forgive me.

```
public List<IJob> AllJobs 
{
    get
    {
        lock(someLockObject)
        {
            // Create a new instance of the list so that the caller would not iterate
            // over the list while it is being modified by another thread
            return _allJobs.ToList();
        }
    }
}

public void AddJob(IJob job)
{
   lock (someLockObject)
   {
       // Add the job to a list
       _allJobs.Add(job);
       // Fire an event
       AvailableJobsChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
   }
}
```

Above code works, mostly thanks to the fact that a lock is thread aware. So when the same thread tries to enter the underlying `Monitor` it gets access immediately. So in our case, some thread calls the method `AddJob`, and the event triggers external code (stil in the same thread context). The external code reads the property `AllJobs` for whatever reason and we're done.

So the scenario (all executed on Thread #1):

- Thread #1 calls into `AddJob`
- AddJob triggers external code through event
- External code reads AllJobs property

When we would rewrite this using a `SemaphoreSlim` it would go horribly wrong.

```
private readonly SemaphoreSlim _sempahore = new();

public List<IJob> AllJobs 
{
    get
    {
        try
        {
            _semaphore.Wait();
            // Create a new instance of the list so that the caller would not iterate
            // over the list while it is being modified by another thread
            return _allJobs.ToList();
        }
        finally
        {
            _semaphore.Release();
        }
    }
}

public async Task AddJob(IJob job)
{
   try
   {
       await _semaphore.WaitAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

       // Add the job to a list
       _allJobs.Add(job);
       // Fire an event
       AvailableJobsChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
   }
   finally
   {
       _semaphore.Release();
   }
}
```

If we would replay the scenario:

- Thread #1 calls into `AddJob`
- Semaphore is taken
- Event triggers external code
- External code reads `AllJobs` property
- Thread #1 deadlocks on getting the semaphore

So, we know we can't simply replace locks with SemaphoreSlims when migrating from legacy "synchronous" interfaces, to more modern async interfaces.

The solution in general is, make sure events are triggered **outside** the lock. Then this problem is solved, and it is still "thread safe".

The above example is the simplest case in our case. We of course also have methods which are longer and are poking in that same list on different ocasions. In these cases, it looks better to have one big lock over the entire method, so that nobody needs to think about corner cases for thread safety. But I am wondering, is it really?

### The "rules" of locking/thread safety

So in the context of all of the above, are there rules of thumbs here? I find myself claiming that it is better to take and release semaphores only when code in interacting with a resource that requires protecting. But I also understand that "it is much easier" to lock the entire method.

I also don't see another approach in case of `SemaphoreSlim`. But that doesn't mean there isn't one. But regardless of that, I would also use `lock` as local as possible. Is that wrong?

### Update after finding some guidelines online

Wikipedia might have an answer, unfortunately for me it pretty much contradicts my earlier approach to lock as fine grained as possible.

> An important property of a lock is its granularity. The granularity is a measure of the amount of data the lock is protecting. In general, choosing a coarse granularity (a small number of locks, each protecting a large segment of data) results in less lock overhead when a single process is accessing the protected data, but worse performance when multiple processes are running concurrently. This is because of increased lock contention. The more coarse the lock, the higher the likelihood that the lock will stop an unrelated process from proceeding. Conversely, using a fine granularity (a larger number of locks, each protecting a fairly small amount of data) increases the overhead of the locks themselves but reduces lock contention. Granular locking where each process must hold multiple locks from a common set of locks can create subtle lock dependencies. This subtlety can increase the chance that a programmer will unknowingly introduce a deadlock.

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock_(computer_science)

So this would suggest to start with locking entire methods whenever possible. Again, this was an option with `lock` statements in above example. I don't know, I feel a bit lost. I am looking for a proper pattern to deal with this situation I guess.

I am a bit concerned changing the way we "guaranteed" synchronous behavior before, which is no longer the case when we move to async await where we use more fine grained locking.

If anybody is still reading this far, and has a better way to deal with these kind of migrations, I am all ears

Comment: Not sure if it's applicable to your task, but you can check out `AsyncLock` from the https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx, which has pretty similar semantics to the "normal" `lock', but is async-friendly.

Comment: My first reaction is to question the overall flow and coupling. Why not include the copy of the list in your event arguments, and have the handler act on that rather than calling back to this class's `AllJobs` property? Why does the event need to be fired from within the lock?

Comment: It's really hard to give good advice on this without understanding the details of the way this list is used. Concurrency issues are not limited to thread-safe object access. For example, these other methods "poking" the list--would it impact their correctness if they do that between the time a job is added and the time the event handler finishes responding? How long does the event handler take to run, and how much impact is there if those other methods have to wait for it to finish before they can access a copy of the list?

Comment: @Serg it's an interesting implementation. The problem I have with moving away from `lock` to "something else" in one line: `lock` allows the same thread to enter the monitor again, a `SemaphoreSlim` or his `AsyncLock` do not. Thanks a lot for sharing though, I didn't know this project, seems interesting and nice feature to make it disposable (using statements are less "bloaty" than try/finally statements)

Comment: @StriplingWarrior that is in fact a very good observation. I think you are spot on, passing the list in the event args would solve the problem that "external code" requires to call the public property and take the semaphore again. Why the event needs to be fired: I don't think there is a good reason, it's how it was initially designed. Of course we could refactor. Maybe we should.

Comment: There are 3 general guidelines for locks: 1) Never, ever invoke end-user code while holding a lock (the current code raising an event while holding a lock violates this guideline). 2) Make the scope as small as possible. 3) If your code needs multiple locks, acquire them in the same order each time.

Comment: @StephenCleary aha, so do I understand this correctly if you state "fine grained locking" over "coarse locking" ? because that seems quite a debate on its own when reading more on this topic. While i must say, fine grained locking makes perfect sense to me too! Coarse grained locking feels like a "quick and simple" approach, but will become painful as code changes over time

Comment: @bas: When I started multithreading, I used coarse-grained locking; but years of writing MT code led me to prefer fine-grained locking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SemaphoreSlim is not reentrant. And it is not about this concrete implementation. In async code it would be very hard, if possible at all to make it reentrant. Because unlike threads, there is no easy way to known on which "async thread" you run currently. And sometimes it isn't even possible to deduce that. And that piece of information is crucial to make a lock reentrant.

But this is XY problem. The real problem is that your code relies on reentrance mechanism, which is not portable to async. And also I (and others like Stephen Cleary: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/04/recursive-re-entrant-locks.html)   believe this mechanism to be dangerous and bad practice to begin with. Even in sync world.

My advice is harsh: either completely refactor the code to not rely on reentrance (preferred) or don't switch to async (if refactor too costly).

Of course there are other issues with the code, like mixing sync Wait() with async WaitAsync() which also may lead to deadlocks. Just don't do this. You can use sync and async locks at the same time (with extra care of course), but not sync and async operations on a single lock.

This last problem however is secondary. Because even if you turn all the relevant functions into async/await variants it will still deadlock. Because the event handler will still try to acquire SemaphoreSlim while already locked. So reentrance is the true issue here.

**EDIT:** There are multiple levels of "thread safety" or rather transactional operations. Because what you are dealing with here is not "thread safety" per se, but rather you want a sequence of operations to be transactional or atomic (all or nothing). This is a lot stronger requirement. The way you use reentrant locking makes the implementation simpler, I acknowledge that. And so refactoring might be painful. I mean functionally you can simply get rid of all locks and just apply a single global (async) lock whenever new job/operation starts. But this might kill performance. To write a transactional and efficient code at the same time is often a great challenge.

However from my experience it is also often the case that the requirement of "transactional" can be reduced. For example perhaps the `List<IJob>` can be converted into `ThreadSafeList<IJob>`, i.e. a thread-safe variant. And then completely get rid of locks. This may lead to an inconsistent behaviour, when after adding an element, the event handler may actually see a different list (because of parallel inserts). But perhaps this is acceptable? That way you preserve simplicity and performance, at the price of inconsistency. And from my experience such inconsistencies often don't matter.

Comment: Yeah I think you actually underline exactly what our problem is. Thanks for putting it in words. *The real problem is that your code relies on reentrance mechanism, which is not portable to async*. That's it. We are kind of "beyond the point of no return". We need to refactor this and get rid of the re-entrant bit. One last question if I may. The async/sync topic. We are aware of  that. But... in above situation, we just can't see the alternative. We **need** to take the semaphore in the property. Properties aren't async. So, how do we get out of that situation? ...

Comment: ... Replace the propery with an async getter? Would that be the only way to do it right?

Comment: @bas yes, replace property with a method.

Comment: `not sync and async operations on a single lock` - `SemaphoreSlim` does support this, and sometimes it's useful to have some sync code and some async code sharing the same lock. But as you say that's secondary; the real problem is the assumption of reentrancy.

Answer (score 2):

Your current mindset will lead you to a world of pain. Multithreading is not easy, and trying to make it easy by locking mindlessly around whole methods that include unknown code (user supplied event handlers) will have the predictable result of making your life miserable. Your program will start to misbehave and have a life of its own. It will do things that was never designed to do, because there was never a clear vision of its desirable behavior. Sprinkling your code with `lock` statements here and there, is one of the easiest ways to create software that nobody will be able to maintain.

**Goal:** Protect the non-thread-safe `List<IJob> _allJobs` field from corruption.
**Solution:** Protect with the `lock` statement all interactions with the `_allJobs`, using the same locker object. It doesn't matter if the method is synchronous or asynchronous. The `lock`-protected sections will acquire the lock for extremely short durations, measured in nanoseconds. Don't do anything else inside the protected sections apart from interacting with the `_allJobs`.

**Goal:** Prevent concurrent invocations of the `AvailableJobsChanged` event handler.
**Solution:** First explain to yourself why you want to do that. There is no component in .NET runtime itself that exposes public events with this behavior. If the caller needs to serialize the invocations, they can do it themselves by using thread synchronization or asynchronous locking or [debouncing](https://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/debounce.html) or [exhausting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64353907/how-can-i-implement-an-exhaustmap-handler-in-rx-net) or whatever. In case the client code contains `AddJob` calls that trigger recursively the event, and they use [non-reentrant synchronization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68955189/is-there-a-version-of-semaphore-slim-or-another-method-that-will-let-the-same-th) like the `SemaphoreSlim` component, they might encounter deadlocks and have to figure out a solution to their problem. It's their problem, not yours.

Comment: Protect with the lock statement all interactions with the _allJobs, using the same locker object. *It doesn't matter if the method is synchronous or asynchronous.* Not sure what you mean by that, lock statements give a compiler error in async context. I know you know, but I don't understand what you mean with that statement.

Comment: @bas there is no problem with using the `lock` in `async` methods in general. The `lock` statement gives a compiler error only when it encloses an `await`. And the `List<T>` class has no method that requires `await`.

Comment: Right, I am afraid my question leaves out an important part that indeed we *need* to call into async methods. But good suggestions and valuable insights. Thx for this!

Answer (score 1):

*When we would rewrite this using a SemaphoreSlim it would go horribly wrong.*

There are a number of reasons why you are having issues here, but the first of them is:

- **There is no point in an async lock if you are not doing any `async` code.** The recommendation to use it exists purely because you can't use `lock` in `async` code.
  Just because `async` is all the rage doesn't mean you should use it to the exclusion of anything else. It makes no sense to use `SemaphoreSlim` just because it looks cool: it's less efficient and more difficult to use.
- This is compounded by the fact you are mixing sync and async locking. **Never do this.** If you use `SemaphoreSlim.WaitAsync`, never use `.Wait`, or you can deadlock. And obviously never use `.Wait` on any tasks which call `WaitAsync`.
- You should also place the `WaitAsync` before the `try` in case it fails (which it could if using a timeout or `CancellationToken`).

So, if you need to use `SemaphoreSlim`, it would look like this:

```cs
public async ValueTask<List<IJob>> GetAllJobsAsync()
{
    await _semaphore.WaitAsync();
    try
    {
        return _allJobs.ToList();
    }
    finally
    {
        _semaphore.Release();
    }
}

public async ValueTask AddJobAsync(IJob job)
{
    await _semaphore.WaitAsync();
    try
    {
        // Add the job to a list
        _allJobs.Add(job);
        // Fire an event
        AvailableJobsChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
    finally
    {
        _semaphore.Release();
    }
}
```

If the code is likely to be reentrant then you would need to find a different locking mechanism. [Stephen Cleary has an example on his blog](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/04/recursive-re-entrant-locks.html), but explicitly warns against using it, as reentrant locks are difficult to code against.

As I say, it makes no sense to use this unless the code you are locking around is itself using `await`.

Otherwise, **just use `lock`**. It's fast, it's simple, and it works fine with `async` functions, **as long as there is no `await` inside the `lock`**.

Comment: @freakish It won't deadlock, because that event handler should not be calling this code in the first place, because it's a synchronous call. No synchronous code should be calling this, that's the point. If you wish to do sync-over-async, that's your risk. I explicitly point that out.

Comment: Actually that changes functionality, because now event handler, which is not async, cannot call GetAllJobsAsync() at all. You can't just remove functionality and say "it's fine". And if you switch event handler to being async then this code deadlocks if the handler calls GetAllJobsAsync() under already locked semaphore. Either way this doesn't solve OPs question. The root problem is lack of reentrance.

Comment: See Stephen Cleary https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/04/recursive-re-entrant-locks.html he warns against using reentrant locks in the first place, although it is  possible to code for it.

Comment: Yes, I agree that reentrance is bad practice. And that should be the answer. As it is I find 90% of your answer confusing and not even addressing the real issue.

Comment: Perhaps. Maybe I misunderstood the thrust of the question (too much prose, didn't read), and was focusing more on the code blocks shown. You're welcome to write your own.

Comment: I will re-read this tomorrow morning. Lot of clear insights, and apologies for the long story in the question. And I indeed did not mention that we are calling async methods in the actual methods we're making thread safe. I understand that making things async for no reason is nonsense, but we're not doing that :). The remark about moving WaitAsync outside try/finally is interesting as well. And I think I am going to fast replacing locks with Semaphore slim. I need to dive into the source code again and re-iterate stuff. Thank you so much for the insights