# What are the differences between AsyncEx.AsyncLock and Scott Hanselman's AsyncLock?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, locking, nito.asyncex

I recently had the need to add an asynchronous variant of the `lock` keyword to one of my applications. There are many implementations to choose from, but the two that most appealed to me were:

- [AsyncLock](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/blob/master/doc/AsyncLock.md) from the [AsyncEx](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx) library.
  Main reason: It's from a widely used library.
- [Scott Hanselman's AsyncLock](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/comparing-two-techniques-in-net-asynchronous-coordination-primitives) which is based on [Stephen Toub's AsyncLock](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/building-async-coordination-primitives-part-6-asynclock/)
  Main reason: It's very simple and I can just paste it into my project without needing a new library.

What are the differences during runtime for the two solutions?
Of course the AsyncEx AsyncLock has more features, but assuming I don't need those, how do the two compare?

Comment: So the assumption is that you won't need to wait with `CancellationToken` support? Just a bare-bone `WaitAsync` with no arguments and nothing else?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Yes.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK the [`AsyncLock`](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/blob/master/src/Nito.AsyncEx.Coordination/AsyncLock.cs) component of the AsyncEx library was authored before the introduction of the [`SemaphoreSlim.WaitAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim.waitasync) API, and the same is also true for Stephen Toub's [`AsyncLock`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/building-async-coordination-primitives-part-6-asynclock/) synchronization primitive. On the contrary Scott Hanselman's [`AsyncLock`](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/comparing-two-techniques-in-net-asynchronous-coordination-primitives) was published after the release of the .NET Framework 4.5 (October 2012), and so it is making use of the aforementioned API. It is actually a very thin and lightweight wrapper around this API.

My assumption is that all these components have the same runtime behavior. It is hard to say it with absolute confidence for the AsyncEx version, because the [source code](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/blob/master/src/Nito.AsyncEx.Coordination/AsyncLock.cs) is quite complex, and it's not contained in a single code file.

My personal preference between those options would be to use none. I find using a `SemaphoreSlim(1, 1)` directly quite convenient, and I am not a fan of (ab)using the [`using`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) statement for purposes other than releasing unmanaged resources.

```
await mutex.WaitAsync();
try
{
    //...
}
finally { mutex.Release(); }
```

It's not much more code than:

```
using (await mutex.LockAsync())
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: > (ab)using the using statement for purposes other than releasing unmanaged resources.

This is not an abuse of using. Using just ensures Dispose() is called, which doesn't necessarily have anything to do with unmanaged resources.

Comment: @Ryan according to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/using) *"The `using` statement ensures the correct use of an `IDisposable` instance"*. Also according to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.idisposable) the `IDisposable` *"Provides a mechanism for releasing unmanaged resources"*. I am not making this up. Releasing unmanaged resources is the stated intended purpose of this interface.

Comment: These are sort of halve-truths though. The using statement *does* ensure the correct use of an IDisposable instance, but from the language spec, it only ensures that .Dispose() is called via duck typing. There are many "disposable" things in the framework that don't implement IDisposable for performance reasons.

The documentation for IDisposable is also notoriously bad. Only the IDisposable pattern (with finalizer) is employed for disposing unmanaged resources. In their own documentation they have an example Dispose method that does nothing but call Dispose on managed objects.

Comment: @Ryan having a public `Dispose` method is not enough. An object in `using` has to be implicitly convertible to `IDisposable`, otherwise the compiler throws a [CS1674](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs1674) error. Do you know of any class in the standard .NET libraries that implements the `IDisposable`, and the `Dispose` does something else than disposing unmanaged resources? I don't know of any. If you also don't know of any, then I think the case is closed: Using the `using` for other purposes is against the C#/.NET designers' intentions.

Comment: @Thordor Classes like StreamWriter feel like obvious examples. StreamWriter.Dispose() exists to flush managed buffers to the stream, and doesn't necessarily even call the underlying Stream.Dispose(). Usescases like this demonstrate Dispose() implementing managed cleanup work which has nothing to do with unmanaged resources, in the framework.

Comment: @Ryan good example. The `StreamWriter` derives from the `TextWriter`, and the `TextWriter.Dispose` is a `virtual` method that does nothing. My guess is that the .NET designers anticipated that at least some of the classes deriving from the `TextWriter` would hold unmanaged resources, and decided to make the base class `IDisposable` to clean them up. The documentation of the [`TextWriter.Dispose`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.textwriter.dispose) links to a document titled "Cleaning Up Unmanaged Resources". Do you have another example, that doesn't involve inheritance?

Comment: @Ryan one egregious example of `IDisposable` misuse that I know of, is the [`ICacheEntry`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.caching.memory.icacheentry) interface. The way you add a value in the `MemoryCache` is to call `cache.CreateEntry`, and then `Dispose` this `ICacheEntry` instance. WTF? The `MemoryCache` is equipped with convenience extensions methods that make this create-dispose pattern optional, but still... This API is not part of the .NET standard libraries though. I don't know who is the original author of this library. What was he thinking?

Comment: C# supports `using` ref structs that can't implement `IDisposable`. https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LgbgpgTglgZgTwDQBMQGoA+ABADAAjAEMp8BnfAXnwDsIB3fAYQAoBKAbgFgAoX7AMz4oEOOWBQArgGNgzfAG9e+FfkFqALPgAiMMgAcA9mQjtFAX17mgA

Comment: IMO `using` has outgrown its roots surrounding unmanaged resources. It is cognitively helpful to be able to know that some clean-up code will be run at the end of the scope. This is heavily leveraged in C++ via the RAII pattern.

Comment: @NickStrupat thanks for the info about ref structs, I didn't know that. As I've learned just now, this is called [pattern-based using](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/using#pattern-based-using). It was introduced in C# 8 (along with .NET Core 3.0, September 2019), because otherwise ref structs could not participate in `using` statements, because these types can't implement interfaces. Personally I'll have to see more evidence about the `using` having outgrown its roots surrounding unmanaged resources, before I am convinced.

Comment: There is no amount of evidence that can disprove the fact that MSDN says `IDisposable` is for unmanaged resources. That said, all of the uses of RAII that aren't about memory management are examples of how using statements can reduce the cognitive load when reading code.

Comment: @NickStrupat ​I am not aware what RAII is. Could you post a few links demonstrating creative uses of `using`? If one person uses something against its intended purpose, it's a misuse. If 10,000 persons do it, it's standard practice in the industry.