# Is there now a .NET SDK equivalent to AsyncEx's AsyncLock?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await, thread-synchronization

I was reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75570920/what-are-the-differences-between-asyncex-asynclock-and-scott-hanselmans-asynclo) and at the time of writing, there were two async locking primitives that were widely used in C#; AsyncLock from the AsyncEx library, and Scott Hanselman's AsyncLock (based on Stephen Toub's AsyncLock).  Neither are officially supported by Microsoft, and for something as fundamental as synchronization primitives I'd really prefer to use a lock that's actually in the .NET SDK/framework and which is official.

Has Microsoft yet introduced anything official to this extent?  ie. an async equivalent to a `lock` block?  If not, are there any plans to do so?  It seems like a rather large oversight.  I know you can use `SemaphoreSlim` to achieve an async mutex, but it's still not a proper locking class.

<sub>**Proper locking class:** a class that provides an `IDisposable` releaser, so that it can be used with the `using` statement.</sub>

Comment: From Eric Lippert (one of the C# designers). Why it's not implemented: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7612602/why-cant-i-use-the-await-operator-within-the-body-of-a-lock-statement/7612714#7612714

Comment: *"I know you can use `SemaphoreSlim` to achieve an async mutex, but it's still not a proper locking class."* -- Why so?

Comment: @Hank You'll notice I commented on that answer as I think it's very badly explained, and got a wise-guy answer from Eric Lippert.  In any case, I'm not talking about using `await` in a `lock` statement here, I'm specifically talking about primitives that are designed to work from within an async context.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias If it were, there would be no need for [Scott Hanselman's AsyncLock](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/comparing-two-techniques-in-net-asynchronous-coordination-primitives).  It provides an `IDisposable` releaser and is a wrapper around `SemaphoreSlim`.

Comment: So you say that the `SemaphoreSlim` is not a proper locking class because it doesn't provide an `IDisposable` releaser? Well, the [`Monitor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.monitor) doesn't provide a releaser either (at least [not today](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/34812 "Add first class System.Threading.Lock type")). Neither does the [`Mutex`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.mutex). Would you say that the .NET currently lacks a proper locking class for synchronous synchronization too?

Comment: It has a `lock` statement for synchronous synchronization which is just like a `using` block.  But yeah, frankly I think the built-in synchronization primitives in .NET could do with a refresh.  They seem to have been cobbled together over time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Has Microsoft yet introduced anything official to this extent?

No. Currently there is [a movement](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/34812) towards a new `Lock` type, that is intended as an alternative for the [`lock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement) statement. AFAIK there is nothing going on in the C# language or the .NET runtime, about an `await lock` statement or an `AsyncLock` type.